# Is this context safe from unintentional rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have two callback methods in my AppContext (because I want to be able to call them from any nested component).

The value of the context is therefore an object.

Following the [Caveats](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) section of the React Context documentation, I put the context value into a `useState` inside `_app.tsx`. Is this the correct approach?

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  
  const [showLoginModal, setShowLoginModal] = useState(false);
  
  [...]

  const [contextProviderObject] = useState({
    showLoginModal: () => setShowLoginModal(true),
    onTooManyRequests: () => alert("You're trying to often. Please wait a bit"),
  });

  return (
    <SSRProvider>
      <AppContext.Provider value={contextProviderObject}>
        <div>
          [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is better to utilize `useMemo` instead of `useState`. Basically same thing, reference of the `contextProviderObject` will be preserved during rerenders, but in case you will need to provide some state variables - you will be able to just add this variable to `[]` deps array so `contextProviderObject` reevaluated.

```js
const contextProviderObject = useMemo(
  () => ({
    showLoginModal: () => setShowLoginModal(true),
    onTooManyRequests: () =>
      alert("You're trying to often. Please wait a bit")
  }),
  []
);
```

Also it would be better to add some useCallbacks to preserver functions references, but anyway, asuming all the consumers of your context will use it as

```
const { showLoginModal } = useContext(...)
```

or similar - that way of "optimizations" is useless due to the `contextProviderObject` is not used directly, only one of its properties which has a stable reference between rerenders. But if you want to have

```js
const ctx = useContext(...); 
// ...
ctx.showLoginModal()
```

then it is ok to wrap Object with useState or useMemo but it is not really worth it, the less composite objects you have in code - the better in terms of all those references trackings.

I'd just use

```
const contextProviderObject = { .... }
```

and just feed it to provider as is, just ensure references of the functions and objects inside of this Object are handled correctly/preserved with useMemo, useState, useCallback.

```js
const [showLoginModal, setShowLoginModal] = useState(false);

const showLoginModalFn = useCallback(() => {
  setShowLoginModal(true);
}, []);

const onTooManyRequestsFn = useCallback(() => {
  alert("You're trying to often. Please wait a bit");
}, []);
// useState + useEffect
// ok as const { showLoginModal } = useContext(...)
// ok as const ctx = useContext(...); ctx.showLoginModal();
const [contextProviderObjectState, setContextProviderObjectState] = useState({
  isLoginModalShown: showLoginModal,
  showLoginModal: showLoginModalFn,
  onTooManyRequests: onTooManyRequestsFn
});

useEffect(() => {
  setContextProviderObjectState({
    isLoginModalShown: showLoginModal,
    showLoginModal: showLoginModalFn,
    onTooManyRequests: onTooManyRequestsFn
  });
}, [showLoginModal, showLoginModalFn, onTooManyRequestsFn]);

// ok as const { showLoginModal } = useContext(...)
// ok as const ctx = useContext(...); ctx.showLoginModal();
const contextProviderObjectMemo = useMemo(
  () => ({
    isLoginModalShown: showLoginModal,
    showLoginModal: showLoginModalFn,
    onTooManyRequests: onTooManyRequestsFn
  }),
  [showLoginModal, showLoginModalFn, onTooManyRequestsFn]
);

// ok as const { showLoginModal } = useContext(...) only
const contextProviderObjectRaw = {
  isLoginModalShown: showLoginModal,
  showLoginModal: showLoginModalFn,
  onTooManyRequests: onTooManyRequestsFn
};
```

But if you have some juniors in your team and you want to ensure everything will go normal in any scenario - stick with `useMemo` example. The only thing that will annoy is size of `depsArray` when context grows.

Comment: Thank you! So the benefit of `useMemo` over `useEffect` in this case, is that we can pass (changing) state variables to it?

Comment: @FlorianWalther Sorry for late response, I guess you meant my useMemo vs yours useState in question - It's just a concern for the future. in case you want to add  `showLoginModal` from useState hook - you will need to update the Object somehow when `showLoginModal` is changed to propagate changes to consumers, it can be done with your useState + useEffect hook (useEffect will watch for changes and will need to call setObject (that you dont have currently)) - with useMemo it will be a bit more convenient.

Comment: @FlorianWalther For your particular case, when `contextProviderObject` and the properties inside of it are never updated - your code is ok, references are preserved between rerenders, but in case there is a chance that something needs to be updated inside of this StateObject - you will need to do some tricks :)